# What is the "Vacuously" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm reading book and found this word "Vacuously" and i didn't find translation for it.

And the context is:

> A conditional statement that is true by virtue of the fact that it's hypothesis is false is often called "Vacuously" true or true by default.

Comment: "its hypothesis" (not *it's*)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cited context is itself vacuous / meaningless / untrue / ungrammatical, ***and*** the relevant sense of ***vacuous*** is domain-specific (and completely unknown to most native speakers).

Comment: How did you fail to find a meaning for it: I just googled it and got this: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)**: In mathematics and logic, a vacuous truth is a statement that asserts that all members of the empty set have a certain property.

For example,

> The statement "*all cell phones in the room are turned off*" will be true whenever there are no cell phones in the room. In this case, the statement "*all cell phones in the room are turned on*" would also be vacuously true, as would the conjunction of the two: "*all cell phones in the room are turned on and turned off*".

The literal meaning of '*[Vacuously](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vacuously)*' is:

> 1. Lacking intelligence; stupid or empty-headed
> 2. Emptied of or lacking content